# Redirect POST request to PUT in express

Tags: node.js, api, express, redirect, http-redirect

Background: I've written a REST API with express, which extends and modifies an old API I wrote in Python. The old API wasn't very RESTful: all "modify/insert/delete" requests were done via `POST`, and the query structure was slightly different to the new API.

In short, I want to write some middleware on my new API to redirect requests in the form of the old API, so that they are handled by the routes of the new API. The middleware needs to be self-contained, i.e. I don't want any individual routes to handle redirection logic.

This requires redirecting requests, obviously. I know that I can do this with the `redirect` method, as in (slight pseudocode):

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if (requestIsOld(req)) {
    return res.redirect(newRoute(req));
  }

  return next();
});
```

And I know that I can ask the client to make a new request with *the same method*, with:

```
res.redirect(307, newRoute);
```

However, this leads to `POST` requests to modify/delete data going to `POST` requests on the new API, which are only handled by the "add" request handlers.

**How do I redirect POST requests and request that the method be changed to e.g. PUT or DELETE**?

Comment: 307 specifically does not allow changing the method. You'd have to either proxy the request or just call the appropriate handler/function.

Comment: is there any statusCode that allows change on the method ? @BrahmaDev

Comment: @turmuka Changing method to GET is possible with 302 and 303. I don't know of any other case.

Comment: yeah, those are the basic redirects. @BrahmaDev

Comment: Have you tried [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) ? You can just add the `?_method=PUT` query string to the URL you are redirecting to with a `POST` req.

Comment: That's interesting; I might look in the source code for that. It does essentially what I want to do. For now I'm going with what Brahma said (calling the appropriate handler), which I think is the most elegant solution.